# MariaDB не берет текст на русском

Tags: java, linux, mariadb, manjaro

Работаю с MariaDB из программы на Java. При попытке ввода русских символов бросается исключение:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: (conn=17) Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA0\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB7...' for column 'Name' at row 1
```

В теории, если бы проблема была в кодировке, он бы взял, но показывал криво.
Из консоли тоже не работает (Manjaro).
В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все же проблема была в кодировке. Такая команда решила проблему:

```
ALTER TABLE logtest CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```